# GetOpenFileName() kills my background open streams :(

Tags: c++, getopenfilename

Its a little strange. Ok so I am working with OGRE game engine which has a "SceneManager" class which keeps some files streams open in background. If i use those streams just BEFORE using GetOpenFileName() those streams work fine, but if I try to use those streams AFTER GetOpenFileName() those strams are found to be closed. Can someone throw some light why GetOpenFileName() is killing my background streams?

```
String Submerge::showFileDialog(char* filters, bool savedialog, char* title)
// need to tweak flags for open/save
{
OPENFILENAME ofn ;
char szFile[255] ;
HWND hwnd = NULL;
//getOgre()->getAutoCreatedWindow()->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW", &hwnd);

ZeroMemory( &ofn , sizeof(ofn) );
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof ( ofn );
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof( szFile );
ofn.lpstrFilter = filters ? filters : "All files\0*.*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex =1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL ;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0 ;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir=NULL ;
if(title!=NULL)
    ofn.lpstrTitle=title;
//ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST ;

MeshLoadTest(); // this is where i use background file streams
bool success = false;
if(savedialog)
    success = GetSaveFileName( &ofn );
else
    success = GetOpenFileName( &ofn );
MeshLoadTest(); // this is where i use background file streams

if(!success)
    return "";
String str;
str.append(ofn.lpstrFile);
return str;
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `GetOpenFileName()` can and will change the current directory of your whole process. This might be interfering with whatever else you have going on.

There is an option called `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR`, but according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839(VS.85).aspx), it's ineffective:

> Restores the current directory to its original value if the user changed the directory while searching for files.
>   **Windows NT 4.0/2000/XP**: This flag is ineffective for **GetOpenFileName**.

You should check the current directory before and after making this call; if it changes then this may be your problem. In that case, add code to save and restore the current directory around the call to `GetOpenFileName()`.

Comment: hmmm that sounds interesting, how to stop this behaviour then?

Comment: Perfecto, that makes sense. I am using winXP and yep the directory does change as the files i browse are always in a different directory. I am a little noob in win32 programming, so only if you can tell me how to record and later restore working directory, please :)

Comment: Look up the `GetCurrentDirectory` and `SetCurrentDirectory` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys and I made another discovery, I used OFN_NOCHANGEDIR and the problem was actually solved (WinXP SP3), maybe they need to update MSDN docs once in a while :P

Comment: Do not rely on undocumented features: they may change in any moment in the future, and your application will suddenly stop working in any future version of Windows. I'd go with the save/restore directory solution.

Answer (score 0):

(This is actually an answer to the other answer, where the source of the problem was identified in the change of the current directory)

To save the current directory:

```
#define ARRSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*(arr)))

//...

TCHAR curDir[MAX_PATH];
DWORD ret;
ret=GetCurrentDirectory(ARRSIZE(curDir),curDir);
if(ret==0)
{
    // The function falied for some reason (see GetLastError), handle the error
}
else if(ret>ARRSIZE(curDir))
{
    // The function failed because the buffer is too small, implementation of a function that uses dynamic allocation left to the reader
}
else
{
    // Now the current path is in curDir
}
```

To restore the path, simply do

```
if(!SetCurrentDirectory(curDir))
{
    // The function failed, handle the error
}
```

.

TIP: use the TCHARS and the generic text mappings functions instead of the *char*s from the beginning of the application: this will avoid you a lot of troubles in future, when your application will need to be compatible with Unicode paths.

Comment: You'll get used to it if you'll have to use a lot of Windows APIs that output strings... but it's not WinAPI's fault, but C's: the C strings can be really hideous. :-S